# Swift 3 - How to achieve the transition effect from Yelp and Geocaching?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

**Effect I Wish to Replicate**

Example 1) https://youtu.be/EgU7BfOJ3BE

Example 2) https://youtu.be/kfBzZeGRSa0

In both examples, the user taps on a bar button item located in the navigation bar, and the *List* view controller segues to the *Map* view controller using the *Flip Horizontal* transition.

I have tried using container views, but cannot seem to get this working (I always get a full screen transition, rather than only the container view transitioning).

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

**Edit**

Here is my attempt so far ([link to the full Xcode project](https://drive.google.com/a/mcmaster.ca/file/d/0B8PqJji13o5uVVlHMGNINnB2OWM/view?usp=sharing)).

ParentVC (one with navigation bar):

```
import UIKit

protocol ButtonPressedDelegate
{
    func buttonPressed(passedData:Bool)
}

class ParentViewController: UIViewController
{
    var delegate:ButtonPressedDelegate? = nil
    var switchValue:Bool = true
    var childViewController:ChildViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func switchButtonPressed(_ sender: Any)
    {
        if switchValue
        {
            switchValue = false
        }

        else
        {
            switchValue = true
        }

        childViewController?.buttonPressed(passedData: switchValue)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "parentToChild"
        {
            childViewController = segue.destination as? ChildViewController
            childViewController?.buttonPressed(passedData: switchValue)
        }
    }
}
```

ChildVC:

```
import UIKit

class ChildViewController: UIViewController, ButtonPressedDelegate
{    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func buttonPressed(passedData: Bool)
    {
        if passedData
        {
            print("Show Blue")
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showBlue", sender: self)
        }

        else
        {
            print("Show Red")
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showRed", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show what you tried first, container views should be the right way to do it. But without showing us the code you tried, you won't get an answer

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski I have added my attempt at a solution and a link to the project.